# Distance between a point and the kernel of a continuous functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

It is a problem in my homework.
Let 
$$
X = \{x \in C[0,1] : x(0) = 0\}
$$ 
with norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty$. Denote 
$$
M =\left\{ x \in X : \int\limits_0^1 x(t)=0\right\}
$$ 
If $\Vert x_0\Vert_\infty=1$ and $x_0\in X$ how to prove that $d(x_0,M)<1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Consider functional
   $$
   F:X\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\int\limits_{0}^{1}x(t)dt
   $$
   and prove that $M=\mathrm{Ker}(f)$ and $\Vert F\Vert=1$.
2. Recall that
   $$
   \mathrm{dist}(x_0,M)=\frac{|F(x_0)|}{\Vert F\Vert}
   $$
   [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/153533/19538) you can find the proof of this fact.
3. For $x\in C([0,1])$ with $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|x(t)|1$ the integral $\left|\int_0^1 x(t)dt\right|$ will attain its maximum for the functions $x(t)=1$ and $x(t)=-1$. But you don't have this functions in the space $X$. So show that 
   $$
   \forall x\in X\quad\Vert x\Vert_\infty=1\implies|F(x_0)|<1
   $$
4. Conclude that $d(x_0,M)<1$

Comment: could you please write it more detailed

Comment: @89085731 Which part of my answer require more detail?

Comment: ||F||=1 I don't know

Comment: As for this part use estimation $$\left|\int\limits_0^1 x(t)dt\right|\leq\int\limits_{0}^{1}|x(t)|dt\leq\int\limits_{0}^{1}\Vert x\Vert_\infty dt=\Vert x\Vert_\infty\int\limits_{0}^{1}dt=\Vert x\Vert_\infty$$

Comment: @89085731 Is there anything unclear now?

Comment: @Norbert But this only tells that $\|F\|\le 1$. For showing it equals to 1, we have to show that if $\|F\|=\alpha<1$ then  there exist an  element $y\in X, \|y\|=1$ such that $|\int_0^1y(t)dt|>\alpha$.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad, indeed consider functions $y_n(t)=\max(1,nt)$ and choose $n$ so that $F(y)>\alpha$.