# Riesz's Lemma for $l^\infty$ and $\alpha = 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Riesz's Lemma says the following: Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $Y$ a proper closed subspace of $X$. Pick $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Then $\exists x\in X$ such that $|x|=1$ and $d(x,y) \geq \alpha$ for all $y \in Y$.

I am investigating why we cannot take $\alpha=1$ in general. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma) says "the space $l^\infty$ of all bounded sequences shows that the lemma does not hold for $\alpha = 1$". I believe there's a simple example but I don't see what to take as $Y$... So what exactly is the example (i.e. $Y$)?

**Edit:** It is unfortunate that Wikipedia states the lemma with the version $>\alpha$. With this version, I do not need the specific space of $l^\infty$ to show that the lemma does not hold for $\alpha = 1$. Let $X$ be **any** normed vector space, and take any $x$ with $|x|=1$. Then $\inf_{y\in Y} d(x,y) \leq d(x,0) = 1$.

As Bombyx pointed out, $l^\infty$ is not reflexive so there should be an example for the version I have stated Riesz's Lemma. Since Wikipedia raised $l^\infty$, I was thinking that maybe there is a (simple) constructive proof for this example. Hence, I was asking if
anyone has any idea on what $Y$ should be.

Comment: For an explicit construction, see my post here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331546/rieszs-lemma-on-l-infty

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is no, because $l^{\infty}$ is not reflexive. A related discussion can be found at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296359/a-stronger-statement-of-rieszs-lemma?rq=1). The credit should be given to the answerer in the other post.