# Counterexample for the stronger statement of Riesz's lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296359/a-stronger-statement-of-rieszs-lemma?rq=1&newreg=b456b188e40743b2a247d7b389112223) is a counterexample for the stronger statement of Riesz's lemma and I don't understand it. Why for all $x$, such that $||x||=1$, there exists $y \in Y$, such that $d(x,y)<1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x$ in the unit sphere of $X$. That is, $x \in C([0,1])$, $\|x\|_\infty \le 1$ and $x(0) = 0$. Then,
$$M := \Big|\int_0^1 x(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \Big| < 1.$$

Now, take an arbitrary $y \in Y$. That is, $y \in C([0,1])$, $y(0) = 0$ and $\int_0^1 y(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = 0$. Let us show
$$M \le \|x - y\|_\infty$$
by contradiction. If this would not be the case, we would have $|x(t) - y(t)| < M$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, hence we would get the contradiction $$\Big|\int_0^1 y(t) \, \mathrm{d}t\Big| \ge -\int_0^1 |x(t) - y(t) | \, \mathrm{d}t + M > 0.$$

It remains to construct $y_n \in Y$ with $\|x - y_n\|_\infty \to M$ as $n \to \infty$. To this end, for any $n$ choose a function $f_n$ with the following properties:

- $f_n \in C([0,1])$ and $f(0) = 0$
- $\int_0^1 f_n(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = 1$
- $|f_n(t)| \le 1 + 1/n$ for all $t \in [0,1]$

It is clear that such functions exist. Now, we set
$$y_n(t) = x(t) - f_n(t) \, \int_0^1 x(s) \, \mathrm{d}s.$$
It is easy to see that $y_n \in Y$ and we get
$$\|x - y\|_\infty \le \max_t|f_n(t)| \, M \le ( 1+ \frac1n) \, M$$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your decision!

I managed to simplify it a bit. If we have $x \in C([0,1])$, $||x|| \le 1$, $x(0)=0$ and $M:=\left|\int\limits_0^1 x(t) d(t)\right| < 1$, we shuld take n, such that 
$$
\frac{M}{1-M}<n.
$$

Then we get $f(t)$:
\[ f(t)  = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{(n+1)^2}{n}t, & x \in [0,\frac{1}{n+1}] \\
      \frac{n+1}{n}, & x \in (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{n}{n+1}] \\
      -\frac{(n+1)^2}{n}t + \frac{(n+1)^2}{n}, & x \in (\frac{n}{n+1},1] 
   \end{cases}.
\].

Let $y(t) = x(t) - M f(t)$. $y \in Y$ and $||x-y|| = ||Mf(t)|| = M \cdot \frac{n+1}{n}<1$. Hense, $d(x,Y)<1$.